# How do i check what type of data in an array is?

Tags: objective-c, types

I am pulling data from a Dictionary to an array. Is there any convenient way to check what data type that data is?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `-isMemberOfClass:` method and/or the `-isKindOfClass:` method to inspect the types of the objects you're looking at. These give you explicit indications of exact class or class hierarchy. `-isMemberOfClass:` indicates whether the object is of a given class, whilst `-isKindOfClass:` indicates whether the object is of a given class, *or* any class which inherits from that class.

Depending on what you're actually examining, and why, you should consider (credit to commenter David) looking more generally at whether the object conforms to a given protocol (`-conformsToProtocol:`) or even just responds to a given selector (`-respondsToSelector:`). You sort of want to ask type questions as generically as you can and still preserve the usefulness of the result.

That said, this is somewhat of an unusual case-- do you really have a dictionary that has values of arbitrary types that can't be known *a priori* from the keys? Tell us more about your data if you want more broad design help.

Comment: Thanks, this is just to control check the data type as i have problems with sorting.

Comment: Also, it's sometimes more appropriate to check for functionality instead of class identity - with `-conformsToProtocol:` or `-respondsToSelector:`

Comment: @David Gelhar: Good point. Will edit into the answer. BTW, are you the David Gelhar of BlitzMail fame?

Comment: @PeterK: Gotcha. If you're just debugging, you can just look at (or log, or whatever) the value of `-class`.

Comment: @David Gelhar: Wow! I wasn't a Dartmouth guy, but had friends who were, and BlitzMail was amazing. I spent a semester poring over your protocol docs in college as inspiration in building a toy mail+IM system maybe 12 years ago. BlitzMail was an extremely elegant, learnable technology supporting sharply focused user use cases. It was great software, in and out, and ahead of its time. Kudos. (Sorry to hijack this thread, wasn't sure how else to send a note!)